# .net Web Api 2 Owin authentication token expires suddenly and often on IIS 8.5

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, token, owin

I used this tutorial http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/ as a base to do a project for REST api on ASP.NET.

The token authentication works great on my development machine. but when I tryed uploading it on a IIS 8.5 production server, I get 401s constantly no matter what I set on the AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan .

I think it has something to do with how the token is generated and the local machine key.

Is there any workaround this issue?

Note: I do not have any control on the IIS server.

Comment: What is the response of /token POST request?

Comment: It can be a problem of authentication and authorization on IIS.

Comment: Found the solution, I didn't understand that you can simply generate a machine key in your local server via power shell and copy it to the web.config, for some reason I thought you had to use the machine key of the server where the api was.         <machineKey validationKey="your value here" 
                decryptionKey="your value here" 
                validation="SHA1" 
                decryption="AES"/>